# pre_get_posts for custom page builder meta box

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I created a page builder meta box. When I click in the sample button, that creates a block of posts layout (which has some Options like *Max Numbers of posts to show*) I need to add custom *Max Numbers of posts to show* override using `pre_get_posts` for each block posts.

For example, I created 5 blocks of posts, with 5 different `pre_get_posts` numbers. What should I do next?

```
function posts_per_page( $query ) {
    $items = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'sample', true ); // get custom pre_get_posts

    if ( is_page_template( 'page-builder.php' ) ) {

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $items );

        return $query;

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_per_page' );
```